# Pandas dataframe not sorting

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
for df in dataframes_list:
    for col in df.columns:
         if col.endswith("Date"):
             # Convert the date column to datetime format
             df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col], format='%d %b %Y')

             #Sort the DataFrame by the date column in descending order
             df.sort_values(by=col, ascending=False, inplace=True, na_position='last',  ignore_index=True)
             df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    
             #Sort the DataFrame by the 'ID column in descending order
             df.sort_values(by='Patient ID', ascending=True, inplace=True, na_position='last', ignore_index=True)
             df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

The above code loops through around 20 pandas dataframes, each consists of 3 columns;
'ID', (int64)
'Date', (DD/MMM/YY, e.g. 24/OCT/23)
'Value'. (string/numerical)

The ID column in each data frame can contain 1 to many rows corresponding with each ID. Then the corresponding cells for each row in the Date and Value can either be blank or contain values, see picture. [unsorted data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiWwM.png)

You will notice some ID rows have cells with data in Date and Value column whereas for the same ID other rows don't. This is fine, however I want the blank rows to be below the rows with data. The approach that works in Excel is to first sort by Date column in descending (Z-A) then on ID column by ascending (A-Z) which works. See attached picture for the same data sorted: [sorted data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpCkB.png)

When i apply the same approach via pandas, step one works absolutely fine, so

**1** - sort 'Date' column in descending (Z-A). correct result when printed[after date sort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Li9pk.png)

| Height_Value | Height_Date | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 1.560 | 2023-03-21 | 941928.0 |
| 1 1.800 | 2023-03-21 | 25207763.0 |
| 2 1.735 | 2023-03-20 | 11043814.0 |
| 3 1.540 | 2023-03-20 | 10198930.0 |
| 4 1.810 | 2023-03-20 | 10777321.0 |
| 5 1.700 | 2023-03-20 | 14287293.0 |
| 6 1.710 | 2023-03-20 | 11023399.0 |
| 7 1.790 | 2023-03-17 | 11043151.0 |
| 8 1.702 | 2023-03-17 | 11024770.0 |
| 9 1.550 | 2023-03-17 | 2762322.0 |
| 10 1.630 | 2023-03-17 | 23001921.0 |
| 11 1.570 | 2023-03-15 | 47839815.0 |
| 12 1.803 | 2023-03-15 | 11025239.0 |

**2** - sort 'ID' in ascending. why are the blank rows not moving to the bottom for each group of ID's. For example below, for ID '493755', row 10 should be where row 7 is so 8, 9 and 10 are blank. For '651255', row 13 and 14 should ib in place of rows 11 and 12 so blank are on bottom.[after ID sort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNFko.png)

| Height_Value | Height_Date | Patient ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 1.800 | 2022-05-13 | 71172.0 |
| 1 1.840 | 2022-12-30 | 411599.0 |
| 2 1.840 | 2019-04-01 | 411599.0 |
| 3 1.850 | 2023-02-06 | 411599.0 |
| 4 1.720 | 2023-01-11 | 493755.0 |
| 5 1.795 | 2020-12-02 | 493755.0 |
| 6 1.720 | 2023-02-10 | 493755.0 |
| 7 |  | 493755.0 |
| 8 |  | 493755.0 |
| 9 |  | 493755.0 |
| 10 1.720 | 2023-03-06 | 493755.0 |
| 11 |  | 651255.0 |
| 12 |  | 651255.0 |
| 13 1.850 | 2022-05-30 | 651255.0 |
| 14 1.850 | 2018-08-22 | 651255.0 |

Very grateful if someone can give insight. I have been stuck on this for more than a month and scoured pandas guides/tutorials all over web, as well as pulling out enough hair to trigger a balding process. I have also tried following approach but recieved same result:

```
mask = df[col].notnull()
filtered_df = df[mask]
blank_df = df[~mask]

filtered_df.sort_values(by=col, ascending=False, inplace=True)
blank_df.sort_values(by='Patient ID', ascending=True, inplace=True)

final_df = pd.concat([filtered_df,blank_df])
final_df.sort_values(by='Patient ID', ascending=True, inplace=True)
final_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
print(final_df.head(20))
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC sorting by multiple columns with define assending/descending order in list:

```
out = df.sort_values(by=['Patient ID','Height_Date','Height_Value'], 
                     ascending=[True, False, False], 
                     na_position='last',  
                     ignore_index=True)
print (out)
    Height_Value Height_Date  Patient ID
0          1.800  2022-05-13     71172.0
1          1.850  2023-02-06    411599.0
2          1.840  2022-12-30    411599.0
3          1.840  2019-04-01    411599.0
4          1.720  2023-03-06    493755.0
5          1.720  2023-02-10    493755.0
6          1.720  2023-01-11    493755.0
7          1.795  2020-12-02    493755.0
8            NaN         NaT    493755.0
9            NaN         NaT    493755.0
10           NaN         NaT    493755.0
11         1.850  2022-05-30    651255.0
12         1.850  2018-08-22    651255.0
13           NaN         NaT    651255.0
14           NaN         NaT    651255.0
```

Comment: ahhhh, no way, it's worked!!!. Could kiss you right now you absolute legend. Cheers man :D